# Communication between Android device and Arduino Microcontroller

Tags: android

I want to transmit data from `Arduino microcontroller` to an Android device, over `USB port`.
I dont have an Arduino ADK board, cant communication take place without this board and just the microcontroller?? How should I go about with this communication? 
Also, `Android 3.1` and further devices have the host mode, how can I use an `Android 2.3.4` accesory mode for communication??

Comment: Host mode and accessory mode are extremely different mechanisms.  If you confine yourself to devices supporting hostmode you should with enough software work be able to use a bare arduino (of the standard form with a usb device port) with a simple adapter cable.  With an ADK / accessory / ADB solution you need an external USB host such as the host shield or ADK board.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the IOIO?  It doesn't use your computer's USB port...but I still think it could be helpful: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10748

Comment: The IOIO is basically just a different hardware platform for the same idea as the ADK (though I think it preceded the Google solution slightly).  It may be slightly cheaper and more capable, but is still a lot just to get communication.

Comment: The only easy to communicate with the Arduino with USB is through a virtual COM (Serial) port - so maybe there's a way to open Serial ports on an Android device?

Comment: Its a virtual com port not a "serial port" but it should be possible to interface that from an android device witb hist mode, baring some software obstruction in the platform.  Some devices do have debug serial ports, but generally only acessable with root and/or kernel mods - at which point you could bypass the arduino's ft232 or atmega8u and substitute a level shifter to 1.8v or whatever the particular android device needs.

Comment: Yes, that's probably possible... but with the advent of the IOIO and similar products, the amount of resources/examples has gone up termendously also.  So it might be worth looking into it.